# QuickSort by different values

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

**Hello!** I have a list of lists like this:

```
list_ = [["a", 1],
    ["b", 3],
    ["c", 2],
    ["d", 2]]
```

I want to sort it every second element and I am able to do that using quicksort.

```
def partition(a, low, high):
    i = low - 1
    pivot = a[high][1]
        
    for j in range(low, high):
        
        if a[j][1] >= pivot:
            i += 1
            a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]

def quicksort_inplace(a, low=0, high=None):
    if high is None:
        high = len(a) - 1
    if low < high:
        p_idx = partition(a, low, high)
        quicksort_inplace(a, low, p_idx - 1)
        quicksort_inplace(a, p_idx + 1, high)
    
    return a
```

**Problem**. I understand how to sort one item at a time, but I don’t understand how to sort my list so that if there are identical items, the sorting occurs alphabetically (by the first item).

**in:**

```
[
    ["a", 1],
    ["b", 3],
    ["c", 2],
    ["d", 2]
]
```

**out:**

```
[
    ["b", 3],
    ["d", 2]
    ["c", 2],
    ["a", 1],
]
```

Comment: When `a[j][1] == pivot`, you don't want to put all the elements in the same part of the partition. Instead partition them on the first element of the list.

Comment: Your example shows a reversed order for the alphabetical sorting on the first item too.  Is that your desired result, or the incorrect output your current algorithm delivers?

Comment: P.S. I hope you're only doing this as a learning exercise, because you'll never beat the built-in Python sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just adapt your pivot value and comparison function to do perform any logic you want, but, as is most often the case, you are looking to do "lexographic" order.
Fortunately, python already implements this logic for you with lists and tuples, comparing the first elements, and if equal, go to the next, before determining which is greater.

Just using

```py
pivot = a[high]
...
if a[j] < pivot:
```

would compare the strings first, then the number. However, you want the other order, and, on top of that, you want numbers reversed.

Easiest is just to create such a `key`that you can sort on.

```py
pivot = (-a[high][1], a[high][0]) # reversed number first, then ordinary letter.
...
if (-a[j][1], a[j][0]) < pivot:
```

Of course, we can use the `key` in the normal sorting routines just as well

```py
sorted(list_, key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
list_.sort(key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
```